# rxjs request data from all subscribers and complete after they've all returned

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, observer-pattern, subject

I'm writing an angular 2 app that has several instances of the same component who need to communicate with each other. They share a communication service to accomplish this.

For this question the components are called WidgetComponent, and the communication service is called CommService.

I need a method on the CommService that any WidgetComponent can call which will return information that is based on information in every other WidgetComponent.

The logical flow is like:

1. WidgetComponent calls CommService.getInfo()
2. CommService requests information from all other widgets
3. All WidgetComponents return info to CommService
4. CommService processes all info once all WidgetComponents have responded
5. CommService returns result to original WidgetComponent

I know how I would to this with the traditional Observer Pattern. It'd be fairly straight forward.

The CommService would have a method onGetInfo and property onGetInfoSubscribers like:

```
var onGetInfoSubscribers = [];
onGetInfo(callback) {
    onGetInfoSubscribers.push(callback);
}
```

Then the CommService would have another method getInfo like:

```
getInfo() {
    var data = [];
    for (var callback in onGetInfoSubscribers) {
        // probably add some logic to ignore the callers info
        data.push(callback());
    }

    // processData is just an arbitrary function that combines all the info from the WidgetComponents
    return processData(data);
}
```

Then each component when it gets created would register with the CommService like:

```
var info = { ... myData ... }
CommService.onGetInfo(function() { return info });
```

Then they each could call the method like:

```
var desiredInfo = CommService.getInfo();
```

This would work fine, but I'm getting into RxJS and observables and they offer a ton of utility functions and I'd like to understand them better and I can't wrap my head around how to implement this fairly simple pattern in RxJS.

I think I need to expose some kind of getInfoObservable in the CommService, then each WidgetComponent needs to subscribe to it, then when the getInfo method is called, the CommService needs to call the next() method the getInfoObservable subject, but then somehow each component needs to return their info to the CommService when the observable fires, and the CommService needs to know when they're all done.

My best shot at the code is in the CommService:

```
private infoSource = new Subject();
public info$ = this.infoSource.asObservable().combineAll(info => processData(info));

getInfo() {
    this.infoSource.next();
}
```

Then in WidgetComponent:

```
private info = { ...myData... };
commService.info$.subscribe(e => return this.info);
```

But I know this is not even close and doesn't work at all.

Any tips to the right direction would be much appreciated.  Especially if they're using the angular 2 version of RxJS.

Comment: After doing more research, I think my head is just in the wrong space here.  RxJS is inherently a push system and I'm trying to force it to pull.

Comment: Exactly, all night I was thinking about this and couldn't find a clue how to do that. Can you share your usecase, we can think how to do in `Rxjs` . Thanks for asking this

Comment: The use case is a "dashboard" of user moveable/resizable widgets who all need to be aware of each other's movements to move out of each other's way. This first part was surprisingly easy to do with observables, because they only need to know their own position and the potential intruder's position.  But after they've all moved out of each other's way, I want every widget to "nestle" towards the top left, to accomplish this, they need to be aware of the location of every other widget.

Comment: For this you can just have them as components and patent component is aware of their positions . That should make it simpler . 

Or ... They all listen to a subject in service , when they change their position .. they inform service about their change .. service updates the subject and all others are aware of their new positions

Comment: I will provide a solution in couple hours once I reach home

Comment: This is the solution that I actually ended up moving towards, the CommSvc just maintains the list of widget positions and then it can direct traffic accordingly.  however, I'm running into the same problem again where I need to know once all widgets have responded on a certain event.  But it seems that RxJS really doesn't want you to code in this manner, or it's not meant for this purpose, so I need to re-architect a little bit.

Comment: Your solution is not anti-rx . Service will have list of components , at least total number of them . When they all updated, it changes its state and all components are notified about that .  I can help you with this solution unless you want to try for yourself .In the case  let me know if you are stuck somewhere .

Comment: If you don't like the idea of storing observables in service , we can store them in components. Each component is notified when another component is plugged. So I know 20 other brothers are listening, I will ask service when any comlonent updates it, when the count reaches the full , I will consider the service value. This looks tedious but very Rx way

Comment: So to solve this, I'll need to maintain a count of subscribers, which is simple since I've implemented an architecture where the commservice now maintains a list of all widgets and their positions, and then if I have a function that requires exactly one response from all subscribers, then I just count each response and trigger the final aggregating event when I count them all?

Comment: change of mind, similar to that but better. I posted a new solution . happiest moment for me in stackoverflow :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution :)

Service code :

```
// records how many components have updated the info
let observersCount$ = new BehaviorSubject(0);

// actual info which components listen to
let info$ = new BehaviorSubject({}); 

/** 
logic which updates info$ when all components shared the info.

This is our lucky thing. 
Subject stores how many observers are listening
When the count reaches the total number of observers, 
we update the info$, which sends info to all the components
**/

observersCount$
    .filter(count => (
           count === info$.observers.length && 
           count !== 0
     )
    .subscribe( () => {
        // perform the calculations etc etc., 
        info$.next( newInfo); 

        // reset the count to 0
        observersCount$.next(0);
    });    

// called by the components to update the info
public updateInfo(){
    // every time a component updates info, I increment 
    observersCount$.next(observersCount$.value+1);

    // do the stuff 

}

public getInfo$(){
    return this.info$;
}
```

Component code :

```
constructor(private service: Service){
    service.getInfo$()
        .subscribe( info => {
           // do something with latest info 
        });
}

... 

// inform  service     
this.service.updateInfo();
```

Comment: great solution! I had no idea that subjects had an "observers" property and it doesn't seem to be discussed in the RxJS docs.  Seems very useful.    Now I need to see if I can take this a little further and see if I can have the components "uncount" themselves or resubmit their data without recounting if something changes in the interim... but that shouldn't be too difficult an extension from here! Probably just need to change the structure of the observersCount subject to be a little smarter than a counter

Comment: I was also not aware, I went through the source code and it was there . No docs mention that, don't know why . Let's solve the rest of the problems

Comment: Can you explain 'uncount'

Comment: Such as the case, I'm trying to gather this info when every component is done moving.  So user moves widget1 into conflict with widget 2, widget2 needs to move out of the way, so it does, it is done moving, so it registers its position with the service, but then it moves into conflict with widget3, who must move, etc etc, some where along the line, some other piece somehow bumps back into widget2, widget2 must move again and reregister it's position, but the service needs to know to not count widget2 twice. I'm probably better off "locking" positions after they move once though.

Comment: you are saying each component can change position more than once, thats complex now ! . We can store the info in the component. If its calling second time it tells service that its calling second time so dont increment. how does that sound ? If we need to store the component info in service, it gets complicated. Ideally service should not be aware of who is calling it

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with.  It's not quite what you're after, but I think it will get you close. I am not aggregating the responses before returning them to the calling widget, but the calling widget will receive all of the responses as they come in.  Maybe you can figure out the aggregator if that is necessary.

I think using a Subject is the best approach here.  A Subject is a type of observable that can be used as both an Observable and an Observer, which makes it capable of two way communication.

My solution uses two Subjects in the CommService.  One processes infoRequested events and one process infoReceived events.  In a scenario where your widget was not both a publisher and subscriber, you could get away with one, but in this case that would cause an endless loop.  So I went with two.

Let's take a look.  This is my CommService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

@Injectable()
export class CommService {

  private infoRequested$: Subject<string>;
  private infoSent$: Subject<WidgetData>;

  constructor() { 
    this.infoRequested$ = new Subject<string>();
    this.infoSent$ = new Subject<WidgetData>();
  }

  //Event that is fired when requesting information FROM a widget
  infoRequested(): Observable<any> {
    return this.infoRequested$.asObservable();
  }

  //Fired from the widget that is requesting information from all widgets
  requestInfoFromAll(widgetName: string): void {
    this.infoRequested$.next(widgetName);
  }

  //Used to send information from a widget after receiving an info Requested event
  sendInfo(widgetData: WidgetData): void {
    this.infoSent$.next(widgetData);
  }

  //Event that returns results after a widget has fired off a request Info from All
  receiveInfoFromAll(widgetName: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.infoSent$
               .asObservable()
               .filter(widget => widget.sendToWidget === widgetName);
  }

}

export class WidgetData {
  constructor(public name: string, public status: string, public sendToWidget: string) {}
}
```

After the initialization we have the infoRequested method.  The widget subscribes to this event and transmits data when it is fired.  It will be fired when something triggers the requestInfoFromAll event.

Next is the sendInfo method which is used by the Widget to transmit it's data.  Finally is the receiveInfoFromAll which will be the receiver for data that is transmitted through SendInfo.  I've applied a filter to this as well, which is used to only send the data to the widget that requested it.

On the component side, I have a component creatively named Widget1Component with widgetStatus and widgetName inputs.

This is my widget1.component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommService, WidgetData } from '../comm.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-widget1',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button type="button" (click)="onGetInfoFromWidgets()">Get Status from all Widgets</button>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let widget of widgets">
        {{ widget.name }} - {{ widget.status }}
    </div>
  `
})
export class Widget1Component implements OnInit {

  @Input() widgetName: string;
  @Input() widgetStatus: string;
  widgets: Array<WidgetData> = [];

  constructor(private commSvc: CommService) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    //Subscribe to event requesting my information
    this.commSvc
        .infoRequested()
        .subscribe(
            //Send my info when asked
            requester => this.commSvc.sendInfo(new WidgetData(this.widgetName, this.widgetStatus, requester))
        );

    //Subscribe to event returning all widget statuses to me
    this.commSvc
        .receiveInfoFromAll(this.widgetName)
        .subscribe(widget => this.widgets.push(widget));

  }

  onGetInfoFromWidgets() {
    this.widgets = [];
    //Trigger comm service to get statuses.
    this.commSvc.requestInfoFromAll(this.widgetName);
  }

}
```

Finally, this is my app.component.html:

```
<app-widget1 widgetName="w1" widgetStatus="red"></app-widget1>
<app-widget1 widgetName="w2" widgetStatus="yellow"></app-widget1>
<app-widget1 widgetName="w3" widgetStatus="green"></app-widget1>
```

When you run the app you will get 3 buttons.  Clicking on any of the buttons should cause the statuses of all widgets to populate under that button.

[image]

That's all.  This was a fun coding exercise.  I hope it gets you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I definitely appreciate the effort and this is way closer than I was.  It's at least getting the information from the other widgets, which I was not.  It's still suffering from the main problem that I'm actually running into again with a different issue, which is that RxJS doesn't provide a way of detecting when all subscribers have responded once.  So in the code you provided, while I'm sure I get all of the data eventually, I have no way of detecting when so that I can trigger the data processing function without some kind of hacky timeout.